# Storyboard made for portrait orientation doesn't fit well for landscape orientation

Tags: ios, uitableview, orientation

I have an iPad app that needs to support both landscape and portrait orientations. I've built my storyboard in portrait orientation and put the constraints accordingly. Everything works fine except a table view. In this table view, I have custom cell's that have the following constraints:

[image]

The code with which I populate the cell's are as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"glossaryCell";
    GlossaryTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ListItem* glossaryItem = [[self.glossaries objectForKey:[self.glossaryTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setLayoutWithGlossaryItem:glossaryItem withTableView:tableView];

    return cell;
}
```

In GlossaryTableViewCell:

```
-(void)setLayoutWithGlossaryItem:(ListItem*)glossaryItem withTableView:(UITableView*)tableView
{
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b>%@</b> :</p>", glossaryItem.name];

    NSString* content = glossaryItem.details[0];

    NSMutableAttributedString* nameWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:name withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];

    NSMutableAttributedString* contentWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:content withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];

    [nameWithStyle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[Colors blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, nameWithStyle.length)];

    [self.glossaryName setAttributedText:nameWithStyle];
    [self.glossaryContent setAttributedText:contentWithStyle];
}
```

A little explanation about the above code: I have texts that contain HTML tags, so I need to parse them into `NSAttributedString`'s to put into `UILabel`'s. Here is the code that parses the texts:

```
@implementation HTMLParser

+(NSMutableAttributedString*)parseText:(NSString*)text withFontSize:(NSInteger)size withFontType:(NSString*)type{
    NSDictionary* optionsDictionary = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};

    NSString* font = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HelveticaNeue%@", type == nil ? @"" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@",[type capitalizedString] ]];
    NSString* stringToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style> p, li{font-family:'%@';font-size:%d;margin:0px;}</style>", font, size];

    NSString* itemWithFont = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", stringToAppend, text];
    NSMutableAttributedString* itemWithStyle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[itemWithFont dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:optionsDictionary documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    return itemWithStyle;
}

@end
```

The `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` function works just fine and calculates the height of each row correctly, but the labels don't fit in them as they should. For example; the labels' heights are calculated as if they were in portrait orientation when they are in landscape orientation. This results in ugly layouts and texts not fitting the labels' rect's.

Here is my `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat tableWidth = [tableView bounds].size.width;
    ListItem* glossaryItem = [[self.glossaries objectForKey:[self.glossaryTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b>%@ :</b></p>", glossaryItem.name];
    NSString* content = glossaryItem.details[0];
    NSMutableAttributedString* nameWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:name withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];
    NSAttributedString* contentWithStyle = [HTMLParser parseText:content withFontSize:16 withFontType:@"Light"];

    CGRect nameRect = [nameWithStyle boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableWidth - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:NULL];

    CGRect contentRect = [contentWithStyle boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(tableWidth - 40, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) context:NULL];
    CGFloat height = nameRect.size.height + contentRect.size.height + 40;

    return height;
}
```

The `+ 40` when calculating `height` is the total length of the constraints in vertical.

Any help or suggestion would be well appreciated.

Comment: "but the labels don't fit in them as they should.". Define `should`.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Post your `heightForRow` method.

Comment: Does the `tableWidth` gives correct size for landscape/portrait?

Comment: Yes, it returns 1024 in landscape and 768 in portrait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56176/discussion-between-lord-zsolt-and-halileohalilei).